# Why is querying date much slower than querying an id?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two SQL queries that I need for my application:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b AS b1
ON a.source_id = b1.id AND a.source_type = 'xxxxx'
LEFT JOIN b AS b2
ON a.source_id = b2.id AND a.source_type = 'xxxxx'
WHERE (b1.user_id = 1 OR b2.user_id = 1);
```

EXPLAIN gives the following:

```
|----|-------------|-------|------------|--------|----------------------------|---------|---------|----------------------|--------|----------|--------------------------------------------|

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys              | key     | key_len | ref                  | rows   | filtered | Extra                                      |

|----|-------------|-------|------------|--------|----------------------------|---------|---------|----------------------|--------|----------|--------------------------------------------|

| 1  | SIMPLE      | a     | NULL       | ALL    | NULL                       | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                 | 437816 | 100.00   | NULL                                       |

|----|-------------|-------|------------|--------|----------------------------|---------|---------|----------------------|--------|----------|--------------------------------------------|

| 1  | SIMPLE      | b1    | NULL       | ALL    | PRIMARY                    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                 | 6      | 100.00   | Using where; Using join buffer (hash join) |

|----|-------------|-------|------------|--------|----------------------------|---------|---------|----------------------|--------|----------|--------------------------------------------|

| 1  | SIMPLE      | b2    | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,index_b_on_user_id | PRIMARY | 8       | database.a.source_id | 1      | 100.00   | Using where                                |

|----|-------------|-------|------------|--------|----------------------------|---------|---------|----------------------|--------|----------|--------------------------------------------|
```

and

```
SELECT *
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b AS b1
ON a.source_id = b1.id AND a.source_type = 'xxxxx'
LEFT JOIN b AS b2
ON a.source_id = b2.id AND a.source_type = 'xxxxx'
WHERE (b1.date = '2021-03-09' OR b2.date = '2021-03-09');
```

EXPLAIN gives the following

```
|----|-------------|-------|------------|--------|---------------|---------|---------|----------------------|--------|----------|--------------------------------------------|

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                  | rows   | filtered | Extra                                      |

|----|-------------|-------|------------|--------|---------------|---------|---------|----------------------|--------|----------|--------------------------------------------|

| 1  | SIMPLE      | a     | NULL       | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                 | 437816 | 100.00   | NULL                                       |

|----|-------------|-------|------------|--------|---------------|---------|---------|----------------------|--------|----------|--------------------------------------------|

| 1  | SIMPLE      | b1    | NULL       | ALL    | PRIMARY       | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                 | 6      | 100.00   | Using where; Using join buffer (hash join) |

|----|-------------|-------|------------|--------|---------------|---------|---------|----------------------|--------|----------|--------------------------------------------|

| 1  | SIMPLE      | b2    | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | database.a.source_id | 1      | 100.00   | Using where                                |

|----|-------------|-------|------------|--------|---------------|---------|---------|----------------------|--------|----------|--------------------------------------------|
```

The indexes are as follows:

```
|-------|------------|-----------------------------|--------------|-------------|-----------|-------------|----------|--------|------|------------|---------|---------------|---------|------------|

| Table | Non_unique | Key_name                    | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |

|-------|------------|-----------------------------|--------------|-------------|-----------|-------------|----------|--------|------|------------|---------|---------------|---------|------------|

| b     | 0          | PRIMARY                     | 1            | id          | A         | 6           | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |

|-------|------------|-----------------------------|--------------|-------------|-----------|-------------|----------|--------|------|------------|---------|---------------|---------|------------|

| b     | 1          | index_b_on_date_and_user_id | 1            | date        | A         | 5           | NULL     | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |

|-------|------------|-----------------------------|--------------|-------------|-----------|-------------|----------|--------|------|------------|---------|---------------|---------|------------|

| b     | 1          | index_b_on_date_and_user_id | 2            | user_id     | A         | 5           | NULL     | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |

|-------|------------|-----------------------------|--------------|-------------|-----------|-------------|----------|--------|------|------------|---------|---------------|---------|------------|

| b     | 1          | index_b_on_user_id          | 1            | user_id     | A         | 1           | NULL     | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |

|-------|------------|-----------------------------|--------------|-------------|-----------|-------------|----------|--------|------|------------|---------|---------------|---------|------------|

| b     | 1          | index_b_on_date             | 1            | date        | A         | 5           | NULL     | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |

|-------|------------|-----------------------------|--------------|-------------|-----------|-------------|----------|--------|------|------------|---------|---------------|---------|------------|

| a     | 0          | PRIMARY                     | 1            | id          | A         | 657         | NULL     | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |

|-------|------------|-----------------------------|--------------|-------------|-----------|-------------|----------|--------|------|------------|---------|---------------|---------|------------|

| a     | 1          | index_a_on_source_id        | 1            | source_id   | A         | 554         | NULL     | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |

|-------|------------|-----------------------------|--------------|-------------|-----------|-------------|----------|--------|------|------------|---------|---------------|---------|------------|
```

I understand that the queries don't really make sense since they're joining the same table on the same data, but this is a simplified version of a larger query that still exhibits the same behaviour.

The first query with the date runs in 0.0021 seconds, however the second runs in about 2 seconds. I'd like to know why there is such a large discrepancy between the two similar queries and if possible I'd like to improve the bad query. `b` is indexed on both `date` and `company_id` so I'm struggling to see where the difference comes from apart from the data type.

An interesting thing I noticed while playing with the query was that if I removed the `OR` from the second query so that it became:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b AS b1
ON a.source_id = b1.id AND a.source_type = 'xxxxx'
LEFT JOIN b AS b2
ON a.source_id = b2.id AND a.source_type = 'xxxxx'
WHERE b1.date = '2021-03-09';
```

then it only takes 0.00055 seconds to execute.

Comment: Could you show us the exact indexes, please? With compound indexes order matters. Also the output of `explain`.

Comment: Run an EXPLAIN and see how both queries are using the indexes

Comment: Just FYI, with reference to your final query, `LEFT JOIN x... WHERE x = ...` is the same as `INNER JOIN x...`

Comment: What is the *data type* of the `date` field?  Is it "just a date," or is it "date *plus time?"*

Comment: I've updated the question with more info 

@MikeRobinson it's just a date field